# Powershell Applying SQL Patches Multiple Servers

Tags: sql-server, powershell, server, patch

I need to apply SQL Server Patches in more than 300 Servers, so, I've created code below and saved it as Apply_SQL_Patch.ps1.

I'm reading a txt file with all servers names and I'd like to connect to them, extract and apply Patch.

The issue is when I execute it, it connect to server, but it's not changing directory to D:\Software\Patch, resulting in an error on next lines:

```
$output = foreach ($cluster in GC "D:\Software\Patch\Servers_List.txt")
{
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $cluster
    cd D:\Software\Patch\
    .\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe /X:D:\Software\Patch
    .\setup.exe /action=patch /instancename=SQL2014 /quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
} 
$output | Out-File -Append D:\Software\Patch\Patch_Result.txt
```

Error below:

> .\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe : The term
>   '.\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again. At D:\software\patch\Apply_SQL_Patch.ps1:5
>   char:2
>   +     .\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe /X:D:\Software\Patch
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe:String) [],
>   CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> .\setup.exe : The term '.\setup.exe' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At D:\software\patch\Apply_SQL_Patch.ps1:7
>   char:2
>   +     .\setup.exe /action=patch /instancename=SQL2014 /quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicense ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\setup.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Patching 300+ Sql Server instances sure sounds like you really need a configuration management solution. That being said, have you copied the patch file to the remote servers too?

Comment: Hi @vonPryz! Thanks for replying! Yes, patch is there on directory named :(

Answer (score 1):

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $cluster
cd D:\Software\Patch\
.\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe /X:D:\Software\Patch
.\setup.exe /action=patch /instancename=SQL2014 /quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
```

I don't think this is going to work like you think.  You're creating a session and then executing three commands *locally*.

Try:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cluster -ScriptBlock {
    cd D:\Software\Patch\
    Start-Process -PSPath '.\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe' -ArgumentList '/X:D:\Software\Patch' -Wait
    .\setup.exe /action=patch /instancename=SQL2014 /quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
}
```

I've replaced the patch extraction command with the one above because the command returns control to PowerShell immediately.  You may need to do the same thing with setup.exe.  I don't have an SQL 2014 instance to test on.

Comment: ! Thanks for your reply! It worked, partially. Now, I was able to connect to server, change directory, extract Patch, but, It wasn't able to execute last line .\setup.exe, resulting on error below ( I've checked and setup.exe exists ) Can you give me some light? Thanks! The term '.\setup.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @AdemirP When I run `SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe`, it runs asynchronously.  It returns control immediately and runs the next line before the extraction has completed.  Try `Start-Process -PSPath '.\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe' -ArgumentList '/X:D:\Software\Patch' -Wait`

Comment: thanks once more! For how long time -Wait will occurs? It's running for a while and it looks like it's freeze. Is it necessary some command to start run next line? Final code is below: $output = foreach ($cluster in GC "D:\Software\Patch\Servers_List.txt")
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cluster -ScriptBlock {
    cd D:\Software\Patch\
    Start-Process -PSPath '.\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe' -ArgumentList '/X:D:\Software\Patch' -Wait
    .\SETUP.exe /action=patch /instancename=SQL2014 /quiet /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms}
}

Comment: @AdemirP It waits until the called process exits.  It's working fine for me as written, but you might need to specify the quiet paremeter: `-ArgumentList '/X:D:\Software\Patch', '/q'`.  It's a 500 MB patch, so it took a few minutes for it to extract on my system.

Comment: @AdemirP Oh, come to think of it, you might need to run `Unblock-File -Path  '.\SQLServer2014-KB4037356-x64.exe'` before you call `Start-Process`.  I've seen Windows treat the file as "copied from an unsafe source" before with Start-Process.  I would connect to the server's console session to see if it's displaying anything.

Comment: Awesome @Bacon Bits! I appreciated a lot your help! It worked as you've said and also I've found "Start-Sleep -s 10" command which worked as well! (y) Thanks!